# Importing python module using only the internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

For a programming class I am taking we do all our work through an online textbook called zybooks. For an assignment about modules, I have to create a program that takes in a bunch of data and then prints it out as a table using a module that would create the table for me. I can't seem to figure out how to import the module over the internet, because if I download it on my computer, the code won't work in the web browser because it can't find the module when the website grades it. Is there any way I could put in a URL or use another program that would allow me to import the module and print out the table of data?

Another small problem I ran into was we are supposed to check for errors in the input and one error we are supposed to look for is multiple commas in an input. I thought I had the right solution but it doesn't always work. Any ideas on how to fix that as well would be appreciated. The code I am referencing is on lines 27-29.

```
print("Enter a title for the data:")
t = input()
print("You entered:", t)
print()

print("Enter the column 1 header:")
c1 = input()
print("You entered:", c1)
print()

print("Enter the column 2 header:")
c2 = input()
print("You entered:", c2)
print()

s = []
i = []

while 1>0:
    print("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):")
    o = input()
    if o == '-1':
        break
    if ',' not in o:
        print('Error: No comma in string.')
        continue
    if ',,' in o:
        print("Error: Too many commas in input.")
        continue

    x, y = o.split(",", 1)
    try:
        val = int(y)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Comma not followed by an integer.")
        continue
    s.append(x)
    i.append(y)
    print("Data string:", x)
    print("Data integer:", y)


import texttable as tt
tab = tt.Texttable()
headings = ['Author Name', 'Number of Novels']
tab.header(headings)

for row in zip(s,i):
    tab.add_row(row)

z = tab.draw()
print (z)
```

as requested here is a sample input and output from the program as it is
[image]

this is what the grader expects for the module to produce 
[image]

Comment: Can you show a sample input and output to your code. Edit your question to make that change!

Comment: I mean the expected input and expected output, not what you are getting currently. I should have worded it better